# SUM of sales (per user) from specific date

Tags: sql, teradata

my first steps with SQL, appreciate your help here. I'm using teradata.

```
SELECT a.userID, a.CountryCD, a.VIPdate,
SUM (b.sales) AS Total_Sales
FROM usertable a
INNER JOIN salestable b ON a.userID = b.userID
WHERE a.VIPdate >= 2019/01/01
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

This will get me the following:

```
userID | CountryCD | VIPdate    | Total_Sales
--------------------------------------------
4521   |US         |11/10/2019  |547
8414   |RU         |13/08/2019  |522
7583   |PL         |25/02/2020  |693
7833   |ES         |13/06/2021  |421
7875   |NL         |20/05/2022  |578
7855   |AU         |18/02/2023  |458
```

Now, if I want to get the individual total sum of sales, from the date they became VIP (a.VIPdate), how do I get them considering the dates are variable and every userID is unique?

Comment: To clarify your question, please show us raw data from both tables, as tabular text, as well as the corresponding expected result.

Comment: Why b.VIPdate and not a.VIPdate in the `WHERE` clause? Also 2019/01/01 is a numeric expression with integer value 2019 and not a date. Better to use standard `date'2019-01-01'`. And it seems you are missing a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: What the datatype of VIPdate? Do you want both the overall sum and the sum after becoming VIP or just the latter? Is there a `salesdate` column in `salestable`? Gordon's query is probabl yclose, just use `max(vipdate)` and remove it from `group by` and use `VIPdate >= date '2019-01-01'

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT u.userID, u.CountryCD, u.VIPdate,
       SUM(s.sales) AS Total_Sales
FROM usertable u INNER JOIN
     salestable s
     ON u.userID = s.userID and
        s.salesdate >= u.VIPdate
WHERE s.VIPdate >= DATE '2019-01-01';
```

Comment: that won't give me the total sales after the VIPdate, this means, when they become VIP

Comment: @FornicadorImplacavel . . . Huh?  That is what the `ON` clause is doing.  If you want to extend this for all VIP dates, then remove the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I get his error SELECT Failed. 5407:  Invalid operation for DateTime or Interval.

Comment: @FornicadorImplacavel . . . You may need the keyword `DATE` before the string.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the image you posted, so I'm just working off your query.  You should be able to do this using a conditional `SUM`:

```sql
SELECT 
  a.userID, 
  MAX(a.CountryCD) AS CountryCD, -- wrap in a MAX() since it's not part of an aggregation
  MAX(a.VIPdate) AS VIPDate,
  SUM (b.sales) AS Total_Sales,
  SUM(
    CASE b.sales_date >= a.VIPdate THEN b.sales END
  ) AS sales_since_VIP -- get sales after VIP date
FROM usertable a
INNER JOIN salestable b ON a.userID = b.userID
GROUP BY a.userID
;
```

You also need a `GROUP BY` like Fred mentions if you want to get the results per each user, otherwise it will do the `SUM()` for all the rows.

Comment: Thanks ravioli it doesn't seem to work as the system tells me the date is invalid

Comment: What are the data types for your `sales_date` and `VIPdate` fields?  You can find this out by running `SHOW TABLE usertable` and `SHOW TABLE salestable` via SQL Assistant.  Just make sure you are in the database that contains these tables, otherwise fully qualify the table name.  Also please post your complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

I've amended the question and now showing the how results would look like

This is a fictitious scene, as I'm dealing with a more complex database

Maybe making this a subquery and get total sales from VIPdate?